# Android width equal to height of a box?

Tags: android, layout

i have an issue with the android layout design.if the screen of my android device is 6 inch in height and 4 inch wide, and if stack 6 boxes one over another each one will have height 1 inch and will take up the entire height. now the width of the stack should be also 1 inch so the width of 3 inches is left next to the pile of boxes. How can i achieve this solution??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking to create a square view, you can create a custom view that overrides the `onMeasure` method. Within the `onMeasure` you can `setMeasuredDimension` to the same value making the view a square.

Ex:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
}
```